# Name of classification algorithm based on gaussian distributions estimated from data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, density-function

Can you help me find the name of this classification method:

Assume we have $n$ dimensional feature vectors we want to classify in two classes.

1. We model the classes as two $n$ dimensional gaussian distributions estimated from the data.
2. We classify a new vector to the class that maximizes the PDF (probability density function) at that point.

Comment: Two component Gaussian mixture model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably [Quadratic Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_classifier).

There are also names for different constraints you could make:

1. Covariance matrices of both classes are equal - [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis).
2. Only diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are non-zero - [Naive Bayes Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)
3. Covariance matrix is identity (diagonals = 1, non-diagonals = 0) - [Nearest Centroid Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_centroid_classifier)